# Git status and pull show no diff between local and remote although they are different

Tags: git, git-bash

I have my branch that also has its remote counterpart.

If I make `git status` after `git fetch` and `git pull` it shows this:

```
$ git status
On branch sandbox/abc
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/sandbox/abc'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

`git pull` when on this branch shows

```
Already up-to-date.
```

But when I check the remote branch commits with web gui and locally with `git log` I see there are differences. Couple of commits commited after branching from main are different, that is in the log I see two excessive commits somewhere on the local branch.

How is this possible? Is this a bug in git?

Comment: What is the output when you run git diff your-local-branch your-remote-branch?

Comment: I did git diff sandbox/abc origin/sandbox/abc. The output was empty.

Comment: Does it seem to fetch anything when you do `git fetch`? Can you check that your local `origin/sandbox/abc` branch contains the missing commits from the actual remote repository? What's the output of `git branch -vv`?

Comment: Not all web GUIs agree with `git log` about which commits to show, or how to show them. However, due to the design of Git, if you have a commit with some hash ID `a123456...` or whatever, and *they* have a commit with hash ID `a123456...` (the same ID), these are *the same commit* with *the same history*. If you have different hash IDs, something is different—files, or the history, or both.

Comment: Nothing fetched with git fetch. I noticed my local branch is basically doubled, has the same branch stack on top of itself (duplicated onto itself) + 1 additional commit. And moreover when I delete the local branch and I checkout it again it comes back the same; that is, it is not synced with the web gui remote branch. But this is probably because the web gui is not showing correctly?